# map() inside map() asynchronous in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create an array from another array

```
let a = ["a", "b", "c", ...]

let b = ["22", "33", "44"]

let desireResult = [
    {
    "name": "a", 
    "age": "22"
    },
    {
    "name": "a", 
    "age": "33"
    },
    {
    "name": "a", 
    "age": "44"
    },
    {
    "name": "b", 
    "age": "22"
    },
    {
    "name": "b", 
    "age": "33"
    },
    {
    "name": "b", 
    "age": "44"
    },
    {
    "name": "c", 
    "age": "22"
    },
    {
    "name": "b", 
    "age": "33"
    },
    {
    "name": "b", 
    "age": "44"
    },
    ...
]
```

this is my code:

```
let profiles = a.map(name=>{
    b.map(age=>{
        return ({"name": name, "age":age})
    })
})
Promise.all([profiles])
```

but **map()** has synchronous functionality. so one way is to use **Promise.all([])** . but what about map() inside a map()?

Comment: Are arrays a and b the same size?

Comment: _"so one way is to use `Promise.all([])`"_ - This won't change anything. Especially not without a `.then()`. But this won't do anything useful either when there's nothing to wait for...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by using `flatMap` and `map` and Here is the working example:

**UPDATE:**

```js
let a = ["a", "b", "c",];
let b = ["22", "33", "44"];

var result = a.flatMap(name=>b.map(age=>({name, age})));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know where is the asynchronous part.

It's basically the same code you have but you don't return anything on the first `map`. I just added a return keyword. I also added `flat()` to convert array of array of objects to a single array of objects.

But you can do it with this code:

```js
let a = ["a", "b", "c"]

let b = ["22", "33", "44"]

let profiles = a.map(name=>{
    return b.map(age=>{
        return ({"name": name, "age":age})
    })
}).flat()

console.log(profiles)
```

Comment: @dcangulo Your output is an array of arrays containing the objects, whereas OP's desired output is an array of objects

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `Promise.all` as there are no asynchronous stuff going on, what you need is a Cartesian product of the two arrays, which can be achieved by using a `reduce`/`forEach` combo like so:

```
let profiles = a.reduce((acc, name) => {
  b.forEach(age => acc.push({ name, age }));
  return acc;
}, []);
```

**Demo:**

```js
let a = ["a", "b", "c"];
let b = [22, 33, 44];

let profiles = a.reduce((acc, name) => {
  b.forEach(age => acc.push({ name, age }));
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(profiles);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let a = ["a", "b", "c"];
let b = ["22", "33", "44"];

Promise.all(a.map((key,index)=>({name: key,age: b[index]})))
.then(r=>console.log(r));
```

Another example :

```js
let a = ["a", "b", "c"];
let b = ["22", "33", "44"];

const myPromise = wait => new Promise(resolve=>setTimeout(()=>resolve(Date.now()),wait));

Promise.all(a.map(async (key,index)=>({name: key,age: b[index], time: await myPromise(Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1)})))
.then(r=>console.log(r));
```